# Tastypie sign-in

Tags: django, tastypie

I would like to create login resource but I can't grasp how to do it :(

I have my UserResource and I think it would be best with a LoginResource as the login method.

```
    class UserResource(ModelResource):
        foreign_key = ForeignKey(ForeignResource, 'foreign_key', null=True)
        ...
        class Meta:
            queryset = User.objects.all()
            allowed_methods = ['post']
            resource_name = 'user'
            authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
            authorization = Authorization()

        def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
            try:
                bundle = super(UserResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
                bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
                bundle.obj.save() 
            except IntegrityError:
                raise BadRequest(_("A user with that username already exists."))
            return bundle
```

So how should I do the LoginResource implementation, this is how far I've gotten :)

```
class LoginResource(ModelResource):
    pass
```

My wish is to send (post/get) /v1/login/ username and password and then if login is successful return the user object like if I had GET /v1/user/1/.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things here,

1. limit user objects to those that relate to the request.user using an authorization class.
2. use prepend_urls on the resource class to tack on login and logout views

As an example: https://gist.github.com/airtonix/5473873

Some of that code could be horribly offensive to people more capable than me, but that is definitely the direction you want to be heading.

Comment: Although you could do this, it occurs to me that simply using Apikey athentication and an authorization class to limit access to records would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        resource_name = 'user'

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
        ]

    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                kwargs = {'pk': user.id, 'api_name': u'v1', 'resource_name': u'user'}
                return self.get_detail(request, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(status=401)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)

    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

Then you can do:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"username" : "me", "password": "l33t"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/
```

And it should give you the user object on successful login.